# vega-lite: synchron selection in multiple chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vega-lite, vega

Is is possible to make a selection in one chart and the same selection gets added onto the other charts aromatically?

Maybe its possible as same as you brush?

```
scale: {
  "domain": {
    "selection": "brush"
  }
}
```

like you do it with the brush.

```
"selection": {
"brush": {
    "type": "interval",
    "encodings": ["x"]
}
```

},

[In this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/Lnz7c36e/19/) you can see what i want to do with vega lite. Is this possible?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any built-in way to do this: here's a 2-year-old feature request asking for the same thing: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3686

Comment: Is there any knowen workaround?